# Elasticsearch : How to setup 3 node cluster + Kibana and ingest data (beats, visualize sample geo-data on map, Elastic Agent)

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, heartbeat

I am currently learning Elasticsearch and am trying to setup a 3 node cluster on VMs.

I need 3 nodes:

- each with 4 cores, 16GBRAM, max 500GB disk space for elastic
- My kibana instance hast 2 cores, 4GB RAM and 10GB disk space, Fleet installed.

In a second phase I also want to setup an optional logstash instance with 4 cores, 8GB RAM and 10GB disk - but only when everything else is working.

Setting up the VMs ist straight-forward.
However, I'm unsure how much disk space I should allocate to my 3 elastic nodes??

I want to achieve these tasks:

1. Use Winlogbeat, Heartbeat and Filebeat to connect sources and fill the dashboards
2. read data sets with geo points (sdample data is sufficient) and show/explore on map

When done, I'd like to repeat the same utilizing Elastic Agent and respective integrations.

How do I configure my cluster, in order to make it communicate and what is a good way to begin with beats?

I have set up 4 Ubuntu 22.04 VMs: 3 for Elastic, 1 for Kibana with the settings above.

As a start I set disk spaces to 50GB for the three Elastic and 10GB for the Kibana node